# Search Filter input ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have class Comopnent :

```
  state = {
   names: ['first', 'second']
  };

  updateSearch = (event) => {
   let updatedList = this.state.names;
    updatedList = updatedList.filter(name=> {
     return name.toLowerCase().search(
       event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
     })
   this.setState({names: updatedList});
  }


 render() {
  const names = this.state.names.map((name) => { return (
    <div key={name}>
      <span>{name}</span>
    </div>
  )})
  return (
   <div>
    <input 
      placeholder="Search" 
      type="text" 
      onChange={this.updateSearch} />
        {names}
   </div>
    )
}
```

When I type some text that agrees with the name, `search` is working, and only that name is showing, but when i remove text from `input` all names should show back, but they don't (only the previously searched name is displayed). Why?

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: Because after removing the name you are not setting up the state to initial one.
this line " this.setState({names: updatedList});" update the state .

Comment: @ashishsherawat So how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
  Add one more val in state as initialName and in updateSearch set updateSearch value 
with initalNames.
Try This.
 state = {
   names: ['first', 'second'],
   intiailNames:['first','second']
 };

updateSearch = (event) => {
 let updatedList = this.state.intiailNames;
 updatedList = updatedList.filter(name=> {
 return name.toLowerCase().search(
   event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
 })
this.setState({names: updatedList});
 }
```

Comment: ok, I discovered myself how to do it well, but anyway thanks for help!